# How to wait for return list from Parse.com to load into List View

Tags: objective-c, listview, parse-platform

*Big picture*: I'm returning a list of names from a Parse.com table and want to display them in a List View in xCode for a mobile touch application.

I can successfully get the list and `NSLog` them for verification.  However, when I assign them to an array within the query nothing is being sent to the view.

Breaking it down for simplicity, if I hard code values to the array before or after the query the list view loads correctly.  If I assign them inside the query then nothing gets loaded to the view.

I suspect the view is loading before the results are finished making the query.

I'm very new to xCode and Parse.com so it might be a simple answer to: **how to tell the list to load after results are returned from within the query?**

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //The next line works here before the query
    //tableData= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Persons"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded. The first 100 objects are available in objects

            NSMutableArray *returnedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                //Log successfully displays the names
                NSLog(@"display name: %@",object[@"firstName"]);
                [returnedData addObject:@"display name: "];
            }

            //Here is where I'm trying to assign the data and nothing happens
            tableData= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];


            NSLog(@"worked");
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            //NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

    //The next line works here After the query
    //tableData= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];
}
```

---

Initialized the array here:

```
@implementation EmProjectViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` executes the block (asynchronously) after the view has been displayed. Thus you probably just forgot to call `reloadData` on the `tableView`. Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Persons"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            tableData= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } 
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I just needed to reload the data.

Answer (score 2):

Chris is correct, the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` executes asynchronously. Here are other things that I would do:

1)I would execute the query in the `viewWillAppear` method instead of the `viewDidLoad`.I find thats its a little late to query in the `viewDidLoad`, it makes your app look less responsive.

2) In the view that you are performing this query, I would add a property with an `NSMutableArray`

1. Use your `NSMutableArray` in the datasource methods.
2. Initialize your `NSMutableArray` to the `objects` array. Like so:

   `self.myPropertyMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];`
3. call `[self.tableview reloadData];` after the query has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

initialize tableData with prefix `__block`
like this:`__block NSMutableArray *tableData;`
if you don't have `__block` in block you only can read,with `__block` you can readwrite.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding this in my initialization but it didn't solve the problem.  I've edited my post to show how I'm initializing the array currently.

Comment: Did tableData get data? If yes,or you just forgot reloadData.add:[_tableView reloadData];after assign data. I download Parse sdk,and write a demo,it worked.download address: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1qW9Bx72 password: falv